# How do I write in a new text file every x lines? [python]

Tags: python, text, split

Let's say I have a list with 10,000 entries. The user inputs a number, say 10. What I need to do is write all of the entries in the list to .txt files, but only 10 to each file. So the program would write the first 10, and then create a new file, and write the next 10... etc.

Thanks

```
count = 0
ext = 0
path = 'New/' + str(ext) + '.txt'
open(path, 'a').close()
for line in flines:
    f = open(path, 'a')
    if count <= x:
        f.write(line)
        count += 1
    else:
        ext += 1
        path = 'New/' + str(ext) + '.txt'
    count += x
    f.close()
```

This is what I've tried, amongst some other solutions. I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple.

This is different to the other question pointed out above as that's talking about a text file and this is talking about a list.

Comment: You seemed to have explained what you want to achieve... But if you could provide with information such as what you have tried out and where you are stuck, then maybe someone will be willing to help you out...

Comment: Alright, let me copy my code.

Comment: What is `sep` in `count += sep` and `x` in `count <= x` ?And it seems you are not resetting the count variable

Comment: *I have a feeling that I'm missing something simple* ... Yes, the brackets in the last line

Comment: @Alfie Fixed. Sep is the same as x. I just renamed sep to x to make it simple. Bhargav: Yeah, I didn't copy it properly. Fixed.

Comment: Aurora, Both sep and x are undefined, so changing sep to x does not help.  And what do you think this does: `open(path, 'a').close()`

Comment: @7stud That creates the file. Also, they're not undefined, they're defined earlier in the program but that wasn't relevant, so I didn't include it. There's only one, sep. I just wrote it as x above as sep doesn't really mean anything here.

Comment: The *simple* thing would be to use `split`. Like this: `split -l $lines_per_file --numeric-suffixes=1 --suffix-length=5 your_file split_prefix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator to split lines list like this:

```
>>> def splited_lines_generator(lines, n):
...     for i in xrange(0, len(lines), n):
...             yield lines[i: i + n]
... 
>>> for index, lines in enumerate(splited_lines_generator(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 2)):
...     with open('new/' + str(index) + '.txt', 'w') as f:
...             f.write('\n'.join(lines))
...
```

I have used `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and 2 just as an example. After running this three files will be created, first two will contain two lines and last one will contain a single line (only `e`). Note that, directory `new` must be present before running this.

Comment: Thank you! Could you comment your code, please?

Comment: @Aurora, at which line you are getting confused at?

Comment: In line two, does len(lines) return the number of entries in the list? What does yield do? What does this mean: 'for index, lines in enumerate' and what's .join()?

Comment: @Aurora, `len(lines)` returns the number of element in the list. `yield` creates a generator function. If you are not familiar with this then please Goole `python yield` or `python generator`. You will get tons of tutorials. This is very powerful concept. `enumerate` is simple. It allows you to get rid of manual incrementing a counter. `join` method joins all elements of a list by using a separator. Here `\n` is the separator.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy do with the [itertools.grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
n = 2

l = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=""):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

for ind, ele in enumerate(grouper(l[:-n], n)):
    with open("new_{}.txt".format(ind), "w") as f:
        f.writelines(ele)
```

If you don't care about losing data just use zip/izip.

To not have any empty lines in the last file and still not lose data, as @Jon Clements suggested we can filter:

```
it = iter(l)
for num, chunk in enumerate(iter(lambda: list(islice(it, n)), []), 1):
    with open('output{}'.format(num), 'w') as fout:
        fout.write("\n".join(chunk))
```

Comment: The lines will already have an EOL character, so `"\n".join(ele)` is going to add blank lines... Might as well use `f.witelines(ele)`

Comment: @JonClements, true I was using a different approach first.  Not sure if the OP wants all the entries on a single line or one per line, the data apparently is coming from a list

Comment: And I suppose the other thing is that the last file may have up to 9 blank lines... whether that's desirable or not I suppose is down to the OP

Comment: @JonClements,  the OP can use zip/izip if they don't mind potentially losing data if the len(l) does not divide evenly by n

Comment: Or just filter out `''s`... or use a different grouping method, eg: https://gist.github.com/joncle/01e548943b4f53aeccaa

Comment: @JonClements, is the original data coming from a file?

Comment: I don't believe so - it's just a code snippet I had laying about... easy to adapt  for any iterable though...

Comment: @JonClements, stole it :),  just  had to use join to separate the data